# Непонятное условие цикла while в C

Tags: c, функции, циклы, while

вообщем добрался в C до расчёта факториала, посмотрел как делают в интернете и нашёл вот это:

```
    unsigned faktorial(unsigned faktor) 
{
    unsigned res = 1;
    while (faktor) res *= faktor--;
    return res;
}
```

тут я что-то сломался и не пойму как в условии цикла может быть "faktor", или я чего то про подпрограммы не знаю?(P.S это подпрограмма)

Comment: перефразируя - пока `faktor` не станет равным нулю в результате выполнения `faktor--`

Comment: @Igor, ааа, вот это конечно я протупил, спасибо.

Comment: В условиях языка Си, всё, что отлично от нуля - это истина. Если это вас смутило...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Цкил while и do {} while проверяет условие следующим образом: если условие в скобках истинно, то цикл продолжается, если ложно, то завершается. Для этого вовсе не обязательно проводить там какие-либо сравнения, достаточно указать переменную, значение которой будет проверяться. Пример:

```
flag = 1;
while( flag )
{
    // делаем что-то полезное
    // Не пора ли нам выходить из цикла?
    if( по_моему_пора )
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Так что в вашем примере почти все нормально. Почти все, потому что следует избегать выражений типа res *= faktor--; - подобный код плохо воспринимается и повышает риск ошибок и багов. Не стесняйтесь расписать действие на несколько строчек - это в дальнейшем сэкономит массу времени и нервов на отладке.